# Has There Been A Change To The AWS Redshift DB Username Validation Constraint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When creating a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream (either in CloudFormation or in the AWS console), I now get a failure to create because of the following error:

> 1 validation error detected: Value at 'redshiftDestinationConfiguration.username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (Service: AmazonKinesisFirehose; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;

My Redshift username is `blah_master_user` and this has been fine while I have been creating (and tearing down!) stacks for the last 6 or more months.

Last week I started getting this error during a stack create and it obviously does not like underscores any more based on that regex in the error message. Just to confirm that is the actual problem, I modified the user name in my stack parameters to remove those underscores and it built successfully.

I have checked the AWS CloudFormation docs and there is no mention of this constraint. I have also noticed that this constraint is only for the redshift username as part of the Kinesis `redshiftDestinationConfiguration` i.e. Redshift itself still happily accepts underscores as evidenced by the fact that the Redshift cluster in my stack completed its create without error when I was running with the underscores in the username last week (and this week, I have tested in a few more accounts to see if it happened elsewhere).

I am at a loss as to what to do next as my account only has basic support i.e. no tech support cases - can anyone help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the fact that it rejects underscores in the username cause a problem for your system that you can't workaround?

Comment: Hi John, yes unfortunately it does - our naming conventions for the db are snake case (as are many organisations I would guess). I feel that we shouldn't have to work around this issue - a breaking change like this should have had some sort of notification, but I cannot find anything mentioning this. I also feel that it may be a mistake because Redshift itself is perfectly fine with the underscores, it is just Kinesis that is complaining :(

Comment: Forgot to add! Many thanks for editing my question and adding that formatting, that looks a lot better! I will make sure I do that in the future :)